# macOS Not Showing Internal Drive on Desktop

Tags: finder, hard-drive, monterey

I'm running macOS Monterey (currently 12.5.1, but this has been happening for a while) and I'm having a problem where one of my internal hard drives is no longer showing it's icon on the Desktop within Finder. Other internal drives show up just fine, so it's not the Finder preferences to show/hide drives on the desktop.

The drive fully mounts on startup, and it's visible in the Locations sidebar when I open a file window. I can navigate to files just fine. It's just missing from the Desktop.

It's annoying -- anyone have any ideas on hidden preferences that I need to change to make it reappear?

Comment: On the "General" tab of Finder Preferences, is "Hard Disks" checked off under "Show these items on the desktop"?

Comment: Yes it is - other internal disks show up as expected. Just not this one.